# Flask app on Apache 2 gives internal server error

Tags: flask, apache2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

I get the following error when running my website on apache2/ubuntu:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'FlaskApp'
[Sun Jan 24 23:04:52.381039 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 25239] [client 190.160.166.19:49593] mod_wsgi (pid=25239): Target WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi' cannot be loaded as Python module., referer: https://www.publimundo.cl/
[Sun Jan 24 23:04:52.381091 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 25239] [client 190.160.166.19:49593] mod_wsgi (pid=25239): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi'., referer: https://www.publimundo.cl/
[Sun Jan 24 23:04:52.381163 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 25239] [client 190.160.166.19:49593] Traceback (most recent call last):, referer: https://www.publimundo.cl/
[Sun Jan 24 23:04:52.381180 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 25239] [client 190.160.166.19:49593]   File "/var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi", line 7, in <module>, referer: https://www.publimundo.cl/
[Sun Jan 24 23:04:52.381185 2021] [wsgi:error] [pid 25239] [client 190.160.166.19:49593]     from FlaskApp import app as application, referer: https://www.publimundo.cl/
```

This is my virtual host configuration:

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin admin@publimundo.cl
    ServerName www.publimundo.cl

    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/FlaskApp/flaskapp.wsgi

    SSLEngine on
    SSLOptions +FakeBasicAuth +ExportCertData +StrictRequire
    SSLProtocol all -SSLv2 -SSLv3

    Timeout 300
    KeepAlive On
    MaxKeepAliveRequests 0
    KeepAliveTimeout 20

    ErrorLog /var/log/site_logs/publimundo-error.log
    CustomLog /var/log/site_logs/publimundo-access.log combined

    <Directory "/var/www/FlaskApp">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
        Require all granted
        Options +FollowSymLinks
     </Directory>

    Alias /static /var/www/FlaskApp/publimundo/static
    <Directory "/var/www/FlaskApp/publimundo/static">
        AllowOverride All
        Allow from All
        Require all granted
        Options +FollowSymLinks
     </Directory>

    #Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/publimundo.cl/fullchain.pem
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/publimundo.cl/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
```

Also the content of flaskapp.wsgi is:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from FlaskApp import app as application
application.secret_key = 'some secret key here'
```

what can be the root of the problem? I have tried many answers on stackoverflow but did not help.

Answer (score 0):

Found my error. The flaskapp.wsgi should be as follows:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
import logging
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stderr)
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/FlaskApp/")

from publimundo import app as application
application.secret_key = 'some secret key here'
```